# Issue using static class properties within a Laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, laravel-queue

I have some logic that works inside a controller but when I execute it in a job, `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`, I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

Within my job, I call a `configure` static method which sets a static property and then references it in the second (`getFiles`) method call.

```
    public function handle()
    {
        NICE::configure([
            'accessKey' => config('nice.credentials.accessKey'),
            'secretKey' => config('nice.credentials.secretKey')
        ]);

        $niceFiles = NICE::getFiles($this->contact->contactId);
```

```
    public static function configure(array $settings)
    {
        ...
        self::$guzzle = new GuzzleClient();

        self::$accessToken = self::getAccessToken();
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Components\NICE;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class Client {

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected static $guzzle;
```

```
    public static function getFiles($contactId)
    {
        $req = self::$guzzle->request('GET', self::apiURL('contacts/' . $contactId . '/files'), [
            'headers' => [
```

There error I'm getting is I'm apparently calling request() on NULL (self::$guzzle).

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function request() on null`

Is there some under-the-hood Laravel magic I'm missing when using static properties and classes in a queued job?

Comment: Well as the error says `self::$guzzle` is null, do you initialize it somewhere?

Comment: @dparoli I forgot to add the code for NICE::configure which I've edited in. That's where I set self::$guzzle.

Comment: Please can you add the $guzzle property declaration?

Comment: @dparoli done--

Comment: IMHO the code seems ok, you need someone more skilled than me in php,  static classes can be tricky. I don't think is something related to Laravel _magic_.

Comment: Wait I see now that you are using a class NICE but $guzzle property is declared on a Client class, is that a typo? If not it's better if you give us some details.